# AngularDart - A directive that implicitly adds a dependency directive?

Tags: angular-dart

Is it possible to have a directive that implicitly adds another dependency directive?

```
@Directive(selector: '[dirA]')
class DirectiveA {
  DirectiveA() { ... }
}

@Directive(selector: '[dirB]')
class DirectiveB {
  DirectiveB(DirectiveA a) { ... }
}

@Component(
     template: '<div dirA dirB></div>'
     //template: '<div dirB></div>' // this is the goal
)
class Foo {}
```

Comment: No, that's not possible. Can you please elaborate why you want to do that? Perhaps there is another way. For example you could make `class DirectiveB extends DirectiveA {}`. There is more to it, but just so that you get the idea.

Comment: I have one directive that adds functionality to an input component to add auto-suggested options. I have a second component that adds auto-suggested options in a specific format from a specific data source. Inheritance might be a good option.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer oops I meant to say I have a second *directive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, unfortunately. As you mentioned yourself, *inheritance* is an option.

For example:

```
@Directive(...)
class AutoSuggestedOptions {}

@Directive(...)
class AutoFormattedOptions extends AutoSuggestedOptions {}
```